How to add Elastic Profiler Auto instrumentation?
I am running a .NET application using IIS Application Pool in windows server, and I want to add Elastic Profiler Auto instrumentation so that I can collect traces and other requests for APM.
I am following below documentation so according to that I need to add environment variables and restart the IIS Application Pool once done, my question is do I need to add these variables directly to the root or under the PATH variable?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/setup-auto-instrumentation.html#setup-auto-instrumentation

Elastic gives some direct examples as to how to do this in an IIS hosted application in the article you linked @ Profiler Auto instrumentation - Internet Information Services (IIS) - .NET Core. It sets the environment variables in the context of the app pool that's hosting your application.
$appcmd = "$($env:systemroot)\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe"
$appPool = "<application-pool>" 
$profilerHomeDir = "<unzipped directory>" 
$environment = @{
  CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING = "1"
  CORECLR_PROFILER = "{FA65FE15-F085-4681-9B20-95E04F6C03CC}"
  CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH = "$profilerHomeDir\elastic_apm_profiler.dll"
  ELASTIC_APM_PROFILER_HOME = "$profilerHomeDir"
  ELASTIC_APM_PROFILER_INTEGRATIONS = "$profilerHomeDir\integrations.yml"
  ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL = "<apm server url>" 
  ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN = "<secret token>" 
}

$environment.Keys | ForEach-Object {
  & $appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='$appPool'].environmentVariables.[name='$_',value='$($environment[$_])']"
}

The instructions for .NET Framework are slightly different, but it's largely the same. You just replace the text CORECLR for COR in matching environment variables.
